# How to pass a date using argparse in Python 3.7+?

Tags: python, python-3.x, datetime, argparse

```
parser.add_argument("-s", "--start-date", dest="start_date", 
                    default=date.today() - timedelta(days = 1), 
                    type=date, help="Date in the format yyyymmdd")
```

This method gives the error

```
argument_test.py: error: argument -s/--start-date: invalid date value: 20181215
```

I assume that argument received is a string and it is incompatible as the object expected is date. So, how do I actually pass the date object? Is there a work around?

I could parse a string and pass it to a date object. But, I'd like to explore other direct options.

Comment: What's this `date` function?  Look at `sys.argv` to see what the shell has pass to your script.  That's what the parser has to work with.  For a start I'd suggest just accepting a string, and doing your own conversion to a data after parsing.  That way you'll get to pay more attention as to how it's being done, without assumptions about what argparse might or might not be doing.

Comment: The `type` parameter is supposed to be a function.  It isn't the name of the expect object type.   It is just doing `date("20181215")`.

Comment: @hpaulji So does it mean, everytime I specify a time, I'm basically invoking a constructor?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a wrapper function that uses `datetime.strptime` to parse the given date string with the desired format:

```
parser.add_argument("-s", "--start-date", dest="start_date", 
                    default=date.today() - timedelta(days = 1), 
                    type=lambda d: datetime.strptime(d, '%Y%m%d').date(),
                    help="Date in the format yyyymmdd")
```

Comment: so the type here is whatever the return type of the function?

Comment: Yes, `type` can be any callable that takes a single string argument and returns the converted value. Please refer to the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#type) for more details.